# How to use contourf in a decision boundary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

First of all, yes, I've searched and tried on my own, but I cannot find nothing useful and therefore I'm stucked. I want to plot `countourf` in a Neuronal Network in Keras.

```
# X = X axis data, Y = Y axis data, Z = predictions (prob of being 1 of each (X, Y)row data)
X.shape = (1701, 1)
Y.shape = (1701, 1)
Z.shape = (1701, )
```

First of all, I've seen that many codes that use `contourf`order its elements from lowest to highest value. Is this necessary?

Second, as [contourf user guide](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html) says,

> X and Y must both be 2-D with the same shape as Z, or they must both be 1-D such that len(X) == M is the number of columns in Z and len(Y) == N is the number of rows in Z.

so my Z has to be `Z.shape = (1701, 1701)` or reshaping `X` and `Y` to 2-D array each one, right?

Which one should be the best option?

PD: I've tried to reshape to `Z.shape = (1701, 1701)`, but I do not know how to give that shape. The idea is to create a plot like the image in this link: [decision boundary](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neural_networks/plot_mlp_alpha.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-neural-networks-plot-mlp-alpha-py)

**EDIT**
What I would like to lnow is how to reshape `Z` if `Z` is a 1701 array of `0 <= value <= 1`, I mean, from `Z.shape = (1701, )` to `Z.shape = (1701, 1701)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the X and Y into a single 2d feature vector X:

```
X = np.vstack((X.reshape((1701, )), Y.reshape((1701, )))).T  # X.shape = (1701, 2)

n_input_dim = X.shape[1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=n_input_dim, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, verbose=0, epochs=1000)

# Plot decision space
plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=150)
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, 0.1), np.arange(y_min, y_max, 0.05))

Z = model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)

plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z, alpha=0.4)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=20, edgecolor='k')
```

On a sample data `X, y = make_moons(100, noise=0.3, random_state=0)`, it would be the plot:

[image]